# Using if with difference in openSCAD

Tags: openscad

I want to create a model in openSCAD
and then I want to cut optionally cut a hole into it (Using difference)

so I can do something like

```
module model_with_hole( hole=false) {
   difference() {
         //the_model()
         if (hole) {
            //the_hole()
         }
   }
}
```

But this is actually saying something like "always cut something out of the model except that what you cut might be nothing if a hole is not required".

another alternative would be:

```
module model_with_hole( hole=false) {
   if (hole) {
       difference() {
         //the_model()
         //the_hole()
       }
   }
   else {
         //the_model()  
   }
}
```

But this is actually saying something like "if you need a hole then render the model and remove the hole, otherwise just render the model".

Is there a way to code this such that the call to render the model would only exist once and the difference action would only happen if required?

```
if (hole) {the_hole()} the_model();
```

So the code would feel more like saying render the model and the if require cut the hole ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:
add the parameters of the holes to a vector and use this vector in a for loop in `difference()`. If the vector is empty, nothing is subtracted from the model, try the four examples:

```
module model(l) {
    cube(size = l, center = true);
}

module hole(pos, dim) {
    translate(pos) cylinder(h = dim[0] + 0.1, r = dim[1], center = true);
}

// holes = [];
// holes = [[[0,0,0],[10, 1]]];
holes = [[[-2.5,-2.5,0],[10, 0.5]], [[0,0,0],[10, 1]], [[2.5,2.5,0],[10, 1.5]]];
// holes = [[[-2.5,-2.5,0],[10, 1]], [[-2.5,2.5,0],[10, 1]], [[2.5,2.5,0],[10, 1]], [[2.5,-2.5,0],[10, 1]], [[0,0,0],[10, 1]]];

difference() {
    model(10);
    for (h = holes) hole(h[0], h[1]);
}
```

Comment: while this is nice, it does not answer my Q.  
From the readability point of view it does not provide the reviewer of this code with the understanding that the hole might need to be cut or not and it seems like there is a list of holes that is always removed from the model.